# Como actualizar informacion de ítem en recyclerView

Tags: android, hilos, recyclerview

¡Saludos amigos!

Estoy trabajando en un reproductor de música, el reproductor me carga el listado de las canciones en un `recyclerView`, cada ítem mostrado en el `recyclerView` esta compuesto por el título, nombre del artista, nombre del álbum y la imagen del álbum, la imagen del álbum la extraigo directamente de la canción verificando primero si no fue extraída con anterioridad ,para extraer la imagen utilizo la clase `MediaMetadataRetriever` y el método `getEmbeddedPicture()` y la guardo en la memoria del teléfono, pero como este método hace que el `recyclerview` se congele, decidí realizar la extracción utilizando un thread, el problema surge porque no se como una vez se haya extraído la imagen utilizando otro hilo notificar desde el thread al `recyclerView` que debe colocar la nueva imagen extraída en el `imageView` correspondiente, para cargar la imagen uso **`Glide`**.

Para resumir mis dudas lo que necesito saber es: ¿Cómo se realiza la actualización de un view de `recyclerView` una vez este ya fue mostrado? Es decir, realizar la actualización de la imagen. 
¿Cómo puedo hacer esto desde otro hilo?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es una vez el guardado de la imagen acabe, notificar al recyclerview que esa celda cambio, entonces al pintar de nuevo la celda preguntar si ya existe una imagen y cargarla. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)

Comment: se que es algo tarde pero aun así quiero darte las gracias, lo que me indicas es lo que deseo realizar, el problema es que no se como puedo notificar al recyclerView desde otro hilo diferente.